# PowerShell SMLets - Cannot Create an instance of an abstract class

Tags: class, object, powershell, powershell-cmdlet, system-center

I am using `SMLets` (A collection of cmdlets that work with System Center) for `PowerShell` to create an object of a class. I know I am not supposed to create objects of abstract classes, but I am not sure what other class I could possible select. I am trying to create a group in `System Center Service Manager`, and the class for a configuration item group as far as I can tell is the one I am entering...

My code is:

```
#Get the name of the class I want to create an object of and store it in a variable
$groupClass = Get-SCSMClass -Name "Microsoft.SystemCenter.ConfigItemGroup$"
#Return the variable stored to ensure this part is working (Debug purposes)
$groupClass

#Get the active status of an object and store it in a variable
$objStatus = Get-SCSMEnumeration -Name System.ConfigItem.ObjectStatusEnum.Active

#Return the variable stored to ensure this part is working (Debug purposes)
$objStatus
#Create the object stored in my class variable and modify the DisplayName and ObjectStatus properties.
New-SCSMObject -Class $groupClass -PropertyHashtable (@{DisplayName = "Test"; ObjectStatus = $objStatus;}) -Debug -Verbose
```

Once I got this code working my idea was to read from a csv file containing a list of all the groups and loop the creation process. However, I keep getting the error: "Cannot create objects of an abstract class"

Am I using the incorrect class to create a group? If so, what is the correct class to select? Is there a more efficient method to do this? Any ideas at all please share, thank you in advance :)

Comment: I know I cannot create an object of an abstract class, so I must be selecting the incorrect class for groups I guess. But it doesnt make sense to me because if I manually create a group in the console then view the object (that defines that group) in the database, it names the class I am trying to use as its base class. So it must be inheriting the properties from this class and extending to create its own sub-class for each group? If so, how can I automate this class creation  through script?

Comment: Another issue is defining the dynamic members of each of these groups... To my understanding this is stored in the XML management pack, this could make things more difficult. Is it also possible to automate the rule creation for dynamic members as well (discovery rule)?

Comment: You might need to use some inline c# code to create a concrete class that derives from the abstract class, e.g. using Add-Type.